# Changing the default binding to open a link in an org mode file using RET

Tags: org-mode, org-link, org-roam

To open a link in an `org-mode` file one normally types `C-c C-o`. I find this rather cumbersome. I would like to rebind the command `org-open-at-point` to `RET` but *only* when the cursor rests on the link.

I am *not* using `evil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set

```
(setq org-return-follows-link t)
```

in your init file (or use the Customize interface to do the same).

Check also `org-tab-follows-link` and `org-mouse-1-follows-link`.

EDIT: Actually, do not change `org-tab-follows-link` - just read its doc string with `C-h v org-tab-follows-link` and heed its pronouncements :-)