# Opening org mode link with ENTER

Tags: org-mode

If I press ENTER on an org mode link, it enters CR in the link.
Is there anything I can do to define ENTER as 'org-open-at-point' when on an org mode link?

Comment: Duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/62731/26163.